# how to distinguish a file with DOS newlines from a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm trying to write a shell script which can determine whether the lines in an input file end with DOS (CR/LF) or Unix (LF) newlines.

How can I make this determination?

Comment: You can use the echo "ASCII" inside your if [ ] and use echo "CR/LF" inside your else

Comment: `file` provides this info and more.  Is there a compelling reason to reinvent it?

Comment: BTW -- my edits here were heavy-handed, but also necessary to have a question allowable by site rules. We very much frown on "please write my program for me" questions -- a question should be specifically focused on a technical problem you've encountered in trying to achieve your goal.

Comment: ...to give a better idea of what I mean about questions being "specifically focused" -- if your question were really about "print[ing] the above", as originally phrased, one would expect it to be about correctly using `echo` or `printf` (and showing what you were doing that had an unexpected result), and not saying anything about the newline type determination at all. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve are good places to start.

Answer (score 2):

If examining the first line is sufficient, something like

```
perl -ne 'exit ($_ =~ /\r$/)' file
```

You could do the same in Bash;

```
lffile () {
    local REPLY
    read -r <"$1"
    case $REPLY in *$'\r') return 1;; *) return 0;; esac
}
```

This requires the `$'\r'` C-style strings of Bash >= 3.x.  If you can reliably and portably embed a literal carriage return character in your script, you could even use `sh` for this, with that minor change.  The following uses a pesky global to hold the carriage return character:

```
lffile_cr=$(printf '\r')
lffile () {
    # local is not POSIX; simply overwrite REPLY
    read -r <"$1"
    case $REPLY in *"$lffile_cr") return 1;; *) return 0;; esac
}
```

In the most general case, a file could have mixed line endings, but if we assume that line endings are consistent (and/or that getting a 50% hit or miss rate for that obscure corner case is acceptable), reading the first line is sufficient.

Comment: Actually `local` _is_ in POSIX but it's not available in some legacy `sh` versions.  I guess it was added to the spec relatively recently (which in these circumstances could mean on the order of 10 years), but haven't checked.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that avoids relying on external tools such as `file` follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- important! not /bin/sh, and do not run with "sh scriptname"

# if given a command-line argument, redirect from it as stdin
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
  exec <"$1" || exit
fi

# Read a single line from stdin into a variable
if ! IFS= read -r line; then
  # we were unable to read a line
  echo "Invalid or Empty"
  exit 1
fi

# Check whether the last character of that line is a CR
case $line in
  *$'\r') echo "DOS" ;;
  *)      echo "UNIX" ;;
esac
```

This works because in bash (though not POSIX sh), `$'\r'` is syntax for a carriage return (CR) character. Since `read` reads up to the first LF seen, in a DOS file, the last character in a line read from that file will be a CR.

Comment: Good solution, but not exactly what the OP asked for. If I understand the question correctly, it is about whether the file *ends* with a LF or CRLF, while you are checking, wheter the *first* LF is preceded by a CR. This makes a difference, when the input file is a binary file, or a file with mixed line endings (some LF and some CRLF), or a file where the last line does not have a line end marker.

Comment: @user1934428 Too lazy to check the OP's original question, but I too interpreted it to mean "where each line ends with ..." as suggested by the topic title.

Comment: @user1934428 Overcame my laziness and fixed the ambiguity in the edited question.  Indeed, the OP originally asked about identifying the file's line endings.

Comment: I still wonder, what is the expected behaviour for a file with mixed endings, or one without any ending at all....

Answer (score 0):

You could start with

```
 last2=`tail -c 2 your_file | od -x -A n`
```

This stores the hexadecimal representation of the last two bytes of your_file in the variable last2. The only problem is the byte order. On a big-endian machine, it will be 0a0d, and on a little-endian machine 0d0a.

Now you could either write your test according to the endianness of your hardware, or you can cheat and write

```
if [ $last2 = 0a0d -o $last2 = 0d0a ]
then
  # Cheating! If the file ends in LFCR, it would incorrectly
  # say that it is CRLF
  echo File ends in CRLF
fi
```

Comment: This will not work reliably with DOS files which do not have a final line ending marker.

Comment: True, but, honestly: If the goal is really to make an educated guess of whether it is a DOS file, I think the safest bet is to rely on the `file` utility, as @John1024 had suggested. Even in your approach, we run into a problem if the file is a binary file which happens to have 0x0d and/or 0x0a in its stream. But in any case, it would be helpful to know, why this classification is needed.